# Scheme (Racket) - Loop Libraries

Tags: scheme, libraries, racket

I have DrRacket Version 5.0.2, I've spent like 3 hours already looking for the right libraries to make `while`, `dolist`, and `dotimes` work. I know how to use them but I just can't find the right libraries. When I type `dotimes` for example it tells me unknown identifier.

PS: Do you have to use `define-syntax` in order to define these loops? I've tried `(require srfi/42)` but it does not work. I'm using `#lang scheme`.

Comment: `while`, `dolist` and `dotimes` are Common Lisp forms. You certainly could write macros for them in Scheme, but maybe you really want a Common Lisp environment instead?

Comment: By the way, `#lang scheme` is a backwards compatibility language and is deprecated so you probably want to use `#lang racket`. Also, I suggest reading [the guide](http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/guide/index.html) as well (it's pretty good for these sorts of questions).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use Racket's [built-in iteration forms](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html) instead:

Instead of `(dolist (x some-list) body-forms ...)`, you can write `(for ((x some-list)) body-forms ...)`

Instead of `(dotimes (i n) body-forms ...)`, you could use `(for ((i (in-range 0 n))) body-forms ...)` or even simply `(for ((i n)) body-forms ...)`, as long as `n` is a non-negative integer.

You could write syntax-rules macros to transform the CL-style loops into Racket-style ones, but it's probably not worth it. Racket's `for`-forms are more flexible than `dotimes` or `dolist` by themselves, since you can easily use them to iterate over several sequences at once.

Comment: Note that the documentation link is to the latest version of Racket, which at the time of this comment is 5.2.  You mentioned that you're using 5.0.2, so be aware of the version difference.

Comment: I only just noticed that for integer `n` you can use `(for ((i n)) ...)` as an equivalent for `(for ((i (in-range 0 n))) ...)`. Neat!

Answer (score 1):

There is also now an implementation of the Common Lisp `loop` macro for Racket. Import it like this:

```
(require (planet jphelps/loop))
```

Answer (score 0):

Number is actually a sequence.

```
> (sequence->list 5)
'(0 1 2 3 4)
```

`(for ((i (in-range n))) body-forms ...)` works too. `in-range` is faster.